When to stratify in a predictive model and which c-statistic to use
I am trying to understand what is the most fair approach to computing the discriminative power of a set of predictors $X$ when I have an additional binary variable $Z$ that I know modifies the risk of an event.
These are my following considerations:

I could fit a model with linear predictor $(Z\beta_z + X\beta_x)$ and then compute the c-statisic using just $X\beta_x$ in each of the levels of $z$ and then average the two c-statistics. Note that $Z\beta_z$ is not utilized in the computation as we don't want to measure its discrimination.

I could fit a stratified cox model with linear predictor $(X\beta_x)$ and compute the c-statistic as above.

I could completely ignore z and just fit a regular Cox model with linear predictor $(X\beta_x)$  and then compute the c-statistic in the standard manner.


I am seeing approach 3) as asking how discriminative is X across all types of patients vs approach  1)2)  being on average how discriminative is x in each stratum? However, I am having trouble deciding when each approach is appropriate? Approach 3) is seeming most appropriate as we could additionally add other risk factors into the model, but I don't think anyone would vouch for that if the main goal is to understand the discriminative properties of $X$ only.

Frank Harrell outlines how to quantify the added predictive value of one or more predictors in binary or survival regressions on this web page. Although he developed the c-index for survival models, he doesn't think that it's useful for that purpose and certainly objects to doing arithmetic on c-indices. Quoting extensively:

Comparing two c-indexes (one from the base model and one from the larger model containing the new biomarkers) is a low-power procedure. This is because the c-index is a rank measure (the concordance probability from the Wilcoxon test or Somers’ rank correlation) that does not sufficiently reward extreme predictions that are correct. And taking the difference between two c-indexes corresponds to taking the difference in two Wilcoxon statistics, which is never done. Instead, a head-to-head comparison is demanded. This can be done by using a different U-statistic based on all possible pairs of observations and counting the fraction of pairs for which one model is “more concordant” with the outcome than the other model. This respects pairings of pairings, and is implemented in the R Hmisc package rcorrp.cens function. Still, this is not as powerful as the likelihood ratio $\chi^2$ test.

If you insist on using the c-index, that could be a way to compare the model with only $Z$ (plus other risk factors not being evaluated) against a model that adds in your predictor set $X$ of primary interest. It's better, however, to use other measures explained on that page: the relative explained variation (rexvar() function in the rms package) or the "adequacy index" (ratio of -2 log likelihoods between the models without and with the predictor set $X$). Either of those then leads to a very intuitive measure of how much the added variables of interest ($X$ in your case, $B$ in the following text) improve the model:

Whether using the adequacy index or relative variation explained, one minus such an index is the fraction of new information provided by predictors in $B$. It is the proportion of explainable variation that is explained by $B$.

